# How to make image view always be center of screen when scale using scroll view?

Tags: ios, swift, view, scrollview

Now I have following view hierarchy:

- View

  - Scroll View

    - Container For Scale View

      - Container For Rotate View

        - Map Image View

          - Arrow Image View

My view hierarchy is a little complicated since I need both scale and rotate, and also I need to keep the relationship of position of map and arrow, I have been working around for a long time and find this solution.

Now My question is how to keep `Arrow Image View` always in center of screen when I scale?

Here is some of my code:

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return Container For Scale View
}

func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let imageViewSize = MapImageView.frame.size
    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size

    let verticalPadding = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
    let horizontalPadding = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2 : 0

    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalPadding, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding, right: horizontalPadding)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  you need some Math

As your scale container view is larger as per your zoom scale you need to convert `center` point relative to super `UIView`

lets say your  Container For Scale View is `viewBase`

```
        var center = self.view.center
```

after that convert your image point same

```
         let convertedImagePoint = self.viewBase.convert(imageView.center, to: self.view)
```

Now get Difff

```
        let diff = convertedImagePoint.y - center.y


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.scrollView1.contentOffset.y += diff
        }
```

Hope it is helps

Comment: Thank you!! It really helps.